# How to access resources from artifactory

Tags: java, android, svn, media, artifactory

What I want to do is to upload only source code and layouts to SVN repository but I also need some media files like .wav, .mp3 etc. Right now these files in my project's raw folder. Is there any alternate way so I can access these files from remote place like any Artifactory. Please note that My application works in offline mode so no internet connection to download these files after application built and installed into device.

Please let me know if there is any way to achieve this using gradle dependencies or anything.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use your buildserver to combine the resources with other build artifacts. Like that you can store them wherever you want. Artifactory might be a good solution since you could store your resources in a versioned manner. Using them is a download call and a copy command. No idea how this works with Gradle, bit shouldn't be too complicated ;)

Comment: I agree with Suresh. You can easily embed the download of the media artifacts from Artifactory into the script or tool you use to checkout your sources from the source control. I would use JFrog CLI to download the media files. BTW, you can also run JFrog CLI from a Gradle task.

Comment: Yes, You are correct. I achieved it with the help of this guidelines   http://jeroenmols.com/blog/2015/08/06/artifactory/